# nutch to extract only pdf files

Tags: apache, hadoop, search-engine, web-crawler, nutch

Is there any way to perform a urlfilter from level 1-5 and a different urlfilter from 5 onwards. I need to extract pdf files which will be only after a given level (just to experiment).

The pdf files will be stored in a binary format in the crawl/segment folder. I would like to extract these pdf files and store all in 1 folder. I have been able to write a java program to identify a pdf file. I cant figure how to make a pdf file with its content having **same font, page #, images** etc.

1. perform crawl
2. merge segment data
3. run makePDF.java

this only identifies pdf files:

```
    String uri = "/usr/local/nutch/framework/apache-nutch-1.6/merged572/20130407131335";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    Path path = new Path(uri, Content.DIR_NAME + "/part-00000/data");

    SequenceFile.Reader reader = null;
    try {
      reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, path, conf);
      Text key = new Text();
      Content content = new Content();
      while (reader.next(key, content)) {
          String contentType = content.getContentType();
          if (contentType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
            //System.out.write( content.getContent(), 0, content.getContent().length );
            System.out.println(key);
          }
      }
      reader.close();
    } 
        finally {
        fs.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content.getContent()` will return the content in bytes.
Just write the bytes to a file using `BufferedOutputStream` and save it as a pdf